# Add Point Features not showing on QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

[image]I have created a shapefile on QGIS 3.10 and have enabled "toggle editing" and need to add point features, but on my QGIS platform the add point feature is not available. I have searched for it in the Help folder, but nothing comes up. Do I need to install a plugin for this or it only accessible on a different version of QGIS?

Comment: Are you really on QGIS 3.1? 3.1 was a development only release that is now 2 years old.

Comment: You have to create a point layer to be able to add points. You have created a polygon layer.

Answer (score 2):

You can find it in the editing toolbar, near the toggle editing button:

[image]

Comment: The QGIS I am using is the 3.10, but my toolbar does not have the "add point feature" icon and when you search for it, nothing comes up. I'm trying to find out why my QGIS might not have it.

Comment: Add a picture of what you see. What is the icon where I have the add point feature.

Comment: I've just added a photo of my toolbar to the original question, thank you!